# MySQL connect to remote server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-connection

I have mysql running on a remote windows server. I am developing a django app that connects to it. It worked well until now 30 minutes ago, I did not set up the remote connection permissions but I had the connection based on my IP and mysql user. How do I find out what are the grants and my problem related information in a mysql shell, I have remote access to that windows server that runs mysql.

[image]

The user is dds, this means If I log in under dds I can connect from any IP address?

Comment: Is the port 3306 allowed on Windows Server? So internal network should work or from internet need port forwarding?

Comment: On the Windows server it is running on Antoher port, not Using default

Comment: Okay, is the non standard port allowed in your firewall (for ingoing connections)?

Comment: When thid didnt work, I was using mobile hotspot. And I've noticed that if I am using home wifi it works.

Comment: Okay, if you using mobile hotspot, than you need your internet ip address. Your router need a port forwarding. you should use: no-ip.com to get a dyn-dns address that your ip is does not mutter! But a database port reached by internet is dangerous!